# Iterate Array/List in Python for Alpha Numeric

Tags: python

What's the best method to iterate through (A-Z + 0-9) on 3 separate occasions that are all exclusive. 
For instance AAA, AAB..AA0, AA1..ZZ0, ZZ1...all the way to 999. There is no restriction in whether a number or character appears in either slot.

```
chars = [string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits]
genned_chars = []
for char in list(itertools.product(''.join(char), repeat=3)):
    genned_chars.append(''.join(char))
```

Where do I go from there?

EDIT:

```
while True:
    chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
    genned_chars = [''.join(i) for i in itertools .product(chars,repeat=3)]
    genned_chars = ['']
    session = requests.session()
    session.headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0_4 like Mac OS X)            AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11B554a Safari/9537.53' }
    page = session.get('URL' + str(genned_chars))

    if page.status_code == '302':
        continue
    else:
        with open("validurls.txt","a") as f:
            f.write( 'URL' + str(genned_chars) + '\n')
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Best method in what sense? Speed, memory, "pythonic way", newbie friendly, shortest code, something else?

Comment: I guess I meant in regards to easiest for me to understand. It's one thing to get the most efficient in terms of speed, but I don't know why it's doing what it's doing then those ms don't matter at all, do they?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's still not as clear as you might think. We don't know how much you already know and what works for explaining something easily to someone may not necessarily work with someone else. Can you also correct the indentation with the `while` statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need to put the string in list and dont use `list` for an generator , and use a list comprehension for join the products  :

```
>>> import string
>>> chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
>>> genned_chars=[''.join(i) for i in itertools .product(chars,repeat=3)]
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked great. Now I'm having trouble importing/using that in my following url. It just outputs www.cnn.com/'' and not the www.cnn.com/'AAA' that I want

Comment: @georgejohnsonnn welcom , its unclear that whats your problem , can you  add your explain to your question ?

Comment: @georgejohnsonnn why you assign the `genned_chars = ['']` ? first and `str(genned_chars)` return the string of the whole list , i think you need loop over the `genned_chars` and add its elements to your url

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without `itertools` by doing three passes through you chars string. I am not sure about performance though (EDIT: I have confirmed this is slower - about *15ms* on my machine - than @Kasra's itertools list comprehension solution above) but it is more clear what you are doing by looking at the code.

```
import string

chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
genned_chars = []

for a in chars:
   for b in chars:
       for c in chars:
           genned_chars.append('{0}{1}{2}'.format(a, b, c))
```

EDIT 2: However, implementing above using list comprehension is faster than using itertools:

```
import string
chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
genned_chars = [a+b+c for a in chars for b in chars for c in chars]
```

Comment: Nice, I did some timings and your EDIT 2 is faster

Comment: However `map(''.join, product(chars,repeat=3))` is faster than yours

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated but maybe helpful depending on what you are doing.

Assume you want to pick a number by index and go straight to that string.

```
>>> import string
>>> chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
>>> len_chars = len(chars)
>>> N = 3
>>> i = 0
>>> ''.join([chars[(i // len_chars**j)%len_chars] for j in range(N-1,-1,-1)])
'AAA'
>>> i = 569
>>> ''.join([chars[(i // len_chars**j)%len_chars] for j in range(N-1,-1,-1)])
'AP3'
```

This could be useful if you are creating a URL shortener for example. You remember what index you are up to, increment it by 1, and return that new combination.